# Find the transformations $T_1$ and $T_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $T_1 \circ T_2 = 0 = T_2 \circ T_1$

$T_1(1,0) = (2,1)$ and $T_2(2,2) = (1,1)$

Find $T_1$ and $T_2$

I know that $T(v) = Av$ but I, not sure how to apply that

Answer (score 0):

Hint: forget the matrix $A$ for now. That is for writing down a full description of the linear map once you've found said full description. Instead, what is $T_1(1,1)$? What is $T_2(2,1)$?

Comment: Im not sure what that means. can you clarify a little

Comment: @Torched90 You're told what $T_1(1,0)$ is. I'm asking whether you can figure out how to use what you're given to find $T_1(1,1)$. Once you've done that, because $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are linearly independent, you can derive the value of $T_1$ for any other vector. Only then should you start worrying about $A$.